# Grant Anonymous access to a Page where broken Inheritance

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, anonymous-authentication

In SharePoint 2013 I hope anyone can answer my common question because I can't seem to find an answer.

I already read all questions here and all over internet to find solution.
What should I do for my case?

How do I grant Anonymous access to a Page where I have broken Inheritance?

When I break inheritance, for Page | Page Permissions | Stop Inheriting Permissions, the Anonymous Users account disappears. How do I use Grant Permissions to specifically assign Anonymous access to the Page? and also to specific user

My case need that scenario ,because I need Anonymous access to all Site with specific user to edit specific page and that page should shown to anonymous

Any solution or fix or workaround is more than welcome